# Force authors to use Manual Excerpt in Wordpress and multiple Manual Excerpts

Tags: excerpt

I'm stuck with this thing. I have a multiple author website and I would like to force them to use the Manual Excerpt before they publish.

Also, I want to display different custom fields for multiple Manual Excerpts so I can use them in some areas in my web, such as the slider or posts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

It is very well maintained  and documented.

It will allow you to add one or more custom excerpt fields, manage the layout in the admin area and make them required so a post cannot be submitted without completing them.